# optimizing subarray max/min analysis in python

Tags: python, optimization, arrays

I'm currently working on a hackerrank problem (found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/angry-children)). in this problem you have to take a given array and find the subarray of length N with the smallest max-min value. the page explains it a little better than I do.

that being said, I've finished the problem and have a solution that I believe works in every case... but I keep on 'timing out' on a select few of the test cases they provide. I've included my code below:

```
def maxmin(array, original, new): 
    minimum = -1
    for i in range(0, original-new-1): 
        subarray = array[i:i+(new)]
        if minimum == -1: 
            minimum = max(subarray)-min(subarray)
        else: 
            if (max(subarray)-min(subarray)) < minimum: 
                minimum = max(subarray)-min(subarray)
    return minimum 


n = input()
k = input()
candies = [input() for _ in range(0,n)]
candies.sort()
print maxmin(candies, n, k)
```

as I said above, the code works fine -- but apparently it's not 'fast' enough. I'm still *very* new to Python (as a quick review of my previous questions would suggest), so I'm not sure how to make this code more 'pythonic' or just faster, in general. any help in this regard would be extremely appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: On which input of the 3 does it "time out"?  0,1 or 2?  And when it "times out" -- how are you notified of this?

Comment: This is more likely to be a brute-force problem rather than 'python not fast enough'.

Comment: @jedwards I'm referring to the inputs given when you submit the code for grading... at which point it times out on 7 - 14.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing so much work?

There are a bunch of things your code does that it doesn't need to do:

- My guess at the worst thing is that it makes a bunch of copies of the list. Each `subarray = array[i:i+new]` creates a new list, which is bad. Note that if you were using numpy, this wouldn't happen, but you'd have other problems. It's much easier to just use elements from the same list, like `array[i]` and `array[i+new-1]`.
- You don't need to calculate the max and min. The list is already sorted, so for any subarray, your [0] value is going to be the min, and your [-1] value is going to be the max. Going to just the array, that means that for a sublist of K values, starting at position i, `array[i]` is the min, and `array[i+K-1]` is the max. This makes things far easier.
- This is a minimal thing, but you can remove a conditional by, instead of setting minimum to -1 to start, setting it to something very, very large. `sys.maxint` is of course the safest, though if you want to avoid importing `sys`, any number larger than you expect to ever see as the difference will work. If you do this, you don't need to have a special case for the first run-through.

Alternatively, you can calculate all the values in an iterator, and then min them. This allows for very compact code; for example, the following works:

```
N,K = (input(),input())
l=[input() for _ in range(0,N)]; l.sort()
print min(l[i+K-1]-l[i] for i in xrange(0,N-K+1))
```

Comment: thanks a ton, @cge! 

I guess I'm still at the stage in programming where I try to think through the problem and then code each and every step my mind takes -- but because I'm not well-versed in the various functions available to me, I end up doing things in a roundabout way. a problem like this one is where I end up having trouble because part of the problem itself is minimizing the work you do. 

all three things you mention make perfect sense to me, and I'll incorporate them into the code I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing to note, your program doesn't work for sample input 2 (the third sample).  Here's a function that works:

```
def maxmin2(array, n, k):
    def unfairness(sub): return max(sub) - min(sub)

    _min = 1e19                 # Sufficiently large to never happen, given the constraints
    for i in range(n-k+1):
        sub = array[i:i+k]      # Extract a k length sublist, starting at index i
        u = unfairness(sub)
        if u < _min: _min = u
    return _min
```

Since it's a *challenge*, I'll leave figuring out the differences between the two functions up to you.

Play around with them, add debugging print statements, etc.  <s>If you can't figure it out I'll edit in a link to the differences in a few minutes that can serve as a pseudo spoiler tag.</s>

**Difference**

It's so small I decided against going through all the hassle.  The problem is in your upper limit to your range function:

```
range(0, original-new-1)
```

The upper limit `original-new-1` is close but off by a little.

Consider `n=5`, `k=2` -- your upper bound would be 5-2-1=2.

So since range excludes the upper bound, i would be `0,1`

So we'd generate the sublists:

- `i=0`, elements in sublist = `0,1,2`
- `i=1`, elements in sublist = `1,2,3`

**But we're never touching elements 4 and 5.**  Instead we need to make our upper bound:

```
    range(0, original-new+1)
                         ^ Sign changed
```

Now our upper bound would be 5-2+1=4 and i would be `0,1,2,3`.  Now, our sublists are:

- `i=0`, elements in sublist = `0,1,2`
- `i=1`, elements in sublist = `1,2,3`
- `i=2`, elements in sublist = `2,3,4`
- `i=3`, elements in sublist = `3,4,5`

And we scan the whole list.  The first two examples gave you correct answers, because the correct answer was found (coincidentally) without needing to consider the unfairness of the last 2 sublists.

**Note**: since we sorted the array in the first place `max` and `min` aren't necessary -- and we can redefine the unfairness function as:

```
def unfairness(sub): return sub[-1] - sub[0]
```

`sub[-1]` is the last element of the sublist and `sub[0]` is the first.  And since it's sorted, we know they are the maximum and minimum value of the sublist respectively.  Further, we can eliminate slicing altogether by:

```
def maxmin2(array, n, k):
    _min = 1e19                 # Sufficiently large to never happen, given the constraints
    for i in xrange(n-k+1):
        u = array[i+k-1] - array[i]
        if u < _min: _min = u
    return _min
```

Comment: thanks! I've checked my code again and it says it works on sample input 2...? the only issues I was running into were ones related to the code timing out on inputs 7, 8, 9, etc. 

thank you very much, again for your code. I'll look through it and try to glean some information!

Comment: @william if the code you're testing is the same code you posted, it most certainly will not work for input 2 -- it will return 20 when then the correct answer is 2.

Comment: @william and when I say input 2, I mean sample input 2 on the problem page (it starts with `10,4,1,2,3,...`) not testcase 2 if you submit it.